# How can I display text always in front on a 3D plot?

Tags: processing

I have a complex 3D plot with some text on rollover. It's already a bit cluttered so I'd like to have the text always be in front of all the plot parts. Like here:

[image: textfront]

Right now, when I hover over some points in the background, the text is sometimes hidden behind plot components, like here:

[image: textbehind]

How can I force the text to always be in the front and facing the camera (which it already is right now).?

Comment: Is this ComplexPlot3D of Wolfram?

Comment: No, it's a custom plot I've created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pushMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html)/[`popMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html) to isolate coordinate spaces: one for the 3D graphics, another for the 2D elements on top:

```
void setup(){
  size(300, 300, P3D);
  sphereDetail(9);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  textSize(21);
  textAlign(CENTER);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  // 3D
  pushMatrix();
    translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 0);
    rotateX(map(mouseY, 0, height, -PI, PI));
    rotateY(map(mouseX, 0, width, PI, -PI));
    sphere(150);
  popMatrix();
  // 2D
  pushMatrix();
    text((int)frameRate, mouseX, mouseY);
  popMatrix();
}
```

(The indenting is not required, just visually emphasising coordinate space nesting.
The last push/pop may not be needed for such as simple example, but is useful if you have more 2D/3D things happening on top of what's already been drawn)

For more info checkout the [2D Transformations Tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/).

Additionally you might find the [PeasyCam library](http://mrfeinberg.com/peasycam/#demos) useful.
To draw 2D text on top you'd do something like:

```
camera.beginHUD();
// draw 2D overlays here
camera.endHUD(); // back to 3D
```